# How much time should you give the google_trackConversion function before leaving the page?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-ads-api

Using Google's asynchronous tracking script `https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js` allows later usage of `window.google_trackConversion({ ... params ... });`

Let's say you are tracking a user clicking a button that changes window.location.href to a new URL.  How long should you timeout that window.location.href change in order to ensure the google_trackConversion made it?  Or is that the wrong approach, perhaps there is a callback for google_trackConversion?  (I don't see it documented if there is one)

Please consider disadvantaged networks such as mobile devices in the answer.

Comment: I noticed there is the HTML5 Beacon API that allows requests after the page is navigated away from.  Unfortunately, that API requires a non-IE/non-EDGE browser as of 2/25/16 according to caniuse.com.  Not sure it would be a perfect fit here anyway, just a thought.

Comment: Google demo for Track outbound links in Google analytics, i couldn't find anything for adwords, https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en